# Is a polymorphic function of higher-kind C[_] ~> D[_] really a natural transformation?

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, shapeless

This is a question about terminology, in scala shapeless library I found the following comment:

```
  /**
   * Base trait for natural transformations.
   *
   * @author Miles Sabin
   */
  trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] extends Poly1 {
```

This defines `F[_] ~> G[_]` as a natural transformation. But I'm not sure if it is abusing terminology, in wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation

it is defined as a structure-preserving morphism between functors. E.g. For the underlying functor `Int => String` of function:

```
v: Int => v.toString
```

A natural transformation can convert it into another functor, like `List[Int] => List[String]` or `Set[Int] => Set[String]`, etc. this seems to indicate that the closest object in scala that resembles a natural transformation is actually the `CanBuildFrom` type class in collection library:

```
trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]

...

object Example extends CanBuildFrom[List[Int], Int, List[String]]
```

which (after currying) is a morphism from a functor `F[_]: Elem => From` to another functor `G[_]: Elem => To`. To my best knowledge, the Poly1 defined by `~>` doesn't have this capability (to take any functor X => Y and yield List[X] => List[Y]), so why is it called natural transformation?

**UPDATE 1**, I think I probably need to clarify. The functor definition in some libraries like cats only include type constructors, like:

```
T => List[T]
```

But by math definition, a functor should probably resembles type lambda, e.g. the following should also be functors

```
T => String
T => List[String] // in that CanBuildFrom example
```

My question is that in this sense, type classes like `CanBuildFrom` should be natural transformation. Yet in shapeless I have no way to define it unless I use ad-hoc polymorphism (multiple implicits in a Poly1 body). So what exactly does this `~>` entails?

Thanks a lot for your opinion

Comment: Turning a `A => B` function into a `F[A] => F[B]` is what a Functor does. A natural transformation is a the capability of turning an effectual value into another effectual value, but of a different effect; no matter which value the original effect has.

Comment: That's interesting, in cats' implementation F`[_]` itself is the functor

Answer (score 2):

Category theory isn't always implementable 1-1 in programming languages. E.g. functor. When you have data structure `F` that allows translation `A => B` into `F[A] => F[B]` it's a functor. But if you use covariance `F[+A]` so that `A <: B` implies `F[A] <: F[B]` you also have a functor but on a type level.

No single structure lets you describe all usages of functor. Theoretically if you had some `F[A] => F[B]` that you can translate into `G[A] => G[B]` and everything that you could compose in `F` should have a corresponding composition in `G`, then you have a functor. But you cannot generate such `F => G` function for everything. You can very easily generate such mapping if you start from `Id`, so merely because of convenience all type classes describing functors only describe a mapping that goes from `Id[A]` into `F[A]` for every `A` where "for every" is handled by generics. And that is just some functor on value level - there are also functors on types. Or on any other multigraphs e.g. you can define transitions between certain values in enum `E1` and then do the same for another enum `E2`, and if one is a subgraph of another and you provide a mapping (some constrained `(E1, E1)` => `(E2, E2)`) - this is also a functor. You wouldn't handle that with just a generic `[A]`. And if you specialized functor implementation for these enums, genericness and composability of `Functor` interface would not be of any benefit. It would be just a function that happens to describe a functor and so what?

This affects natural transformations. In practice the only natural transformations that we are describing in Cats or similar are natural transformations between `Id[A] => F[A]` and `Id[A] => G[A]`. They are easy to implement because you are basically appending `F[A] => G[A]` after `Id[A] => F[A]` to obtain `Id[A] => G[A]`. Not so easy in the general case.

These are still functors and natural transformations. It's just for our practical purposes we only consider functors and NT starting from `Id` because we can create them often, easily and cheaply. Generics/parametric types give you a mapping `A` => `F[A]` for every `A` for free and we just build on it. You could start using `~>` for functors and then create a functors working on such functors (natural transformations)... but you would quickly discover that something like `(A ~> B) ~> (C ~> D)` while models a nice idea, is also very impractical to use. The same is true for a lot of concepts in math. We don't model them perfectly, but only use certain specialization which are of use to us in a certain context.

Answer (score 1):

A functor as normally viewed from functional programming perspective is a pair of things: a type constructor, and an implementation of a specific function, usually called `map`, for that constructor. See [this](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html) or [this](https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/functor).

Thus, `List` together with its specific `map` implementation is a functor. `Option` together with its specific `map` is a functor. `List[String]` is not a functor. `Option[String]` is not a functor. `String` is not a functor.

A natural transformation is a mapping between functors (that satisfies a naturality condition, but let's leave that for another day). This mapping is a family of functions, one for each type, or a polymorphic function if you will. For example,

```
def safeHead[A](l:List[A]): Option[A] = ???
```

is a natural transformation. For any type `A`, it transforms `List[A]` to `Option[A]`, and it always does that in exactly the same way, whatever `A` is. This "for any type `A`" part is an essential part of the definition of what a natural transformation is. A function of type `List[String]=>List[Int]` is not a natural transformation. A function of type `String=>Int` is not a natural transformation.

The above definition is fine but it doesn't let us state "this is a natural transformation" *in Scala*. We can examine each individual function and decide whether it is a natural transformation or not, but what about a *type* of all natural transformations? Let's fix that.

```
trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] extends Poly1 {
```

This line is just the beginning of the definition of what a natural transformation *trait* is. The essential part comes after the `{`.

```
    def apply[T](f : F[T]) : G[T]
```

This method transforms `F[T]` to `G[T]` *for any type* `T`, that is, it's a natural transformation according to our previous definition. A natural transformation according to the "fixed" definition is any object that implements such method.

`CanBuildFrom` is not a natural transformation. It transforms *specific* collections, rather than functors. For example, you can have a `CanBuildFrom[List[String], String, List[String]]`. This is a *very* different type from `List ~> Option`.

Comment: Wow, I really like this answer but I'm not sure if it should deviate that much from its math origin. You are right that CanBuildFrom is not, but how about the first part of its currying form? CanBuildFrom[List[_], _, List[_]]

Comment: @tribbloid Let's see. `safeHead` is definitely a natural transformation. Can you implement it as an extension of `CanBuildFrom`? `object safeHead extends CanBuildFrom[?, ?, ?] { def apply ??? }`